# How to decode sigscripts, figure out the content and test by me whether the transaction is valid?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin

I have a doubt about 3 types of transactions, I am using the portal https://www.blockchain.com/explorer.

Type 1 transactions:
(hash: 9581e8a4c0648fba5aeb5664a1400f0fefeccb28b24cc548b9765e9d7ed287b5)

1Pnmk3ZXg-43z5Ca4xx

Pkscript

OP_DUP OP_HASH160

f9fad59a09d366c842a14530d9b9cb17e572cff2

OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG

Sigscript
4730440220567ee69b22ff82ec625497045bf059c326ad3d4a31f283f787431544abb9df780220239343d7ed165736cfd9c0ec1b9a2e7c8cbe9b1d3781de6388f01d7c21de18b101210217aa2928a6201dce25ce515816666738bbe67a847f9e5b0f2313a4ce39862103

In this case I have the sigscript in hexadecimal but I don't understand how I can interpret it so that, inserted into the pkscript this validates the transaction for me, is there any tool to extract the information to then insert into the pkscript? I know it should contain a public key and a signature. This sigscritp what is it , a sequence of transactions and then public key and signature ?

Type 2 transactions:
(hash: b25cdf4539e68e7b86aa594a87cd669f16786f7546820699b5f942ad18e9dcf0)

bc1qm34ls-wf0j77s3h

Pkscript

OP_0

dc6bf86354105de2fcd9868a2b0376d6731cb92f

Witness
3045022100c6a51d722ccb89159e4c0da69caff14f6e35ca6e8c59be2b3fa095266102181a022030d8db009920c6f489efb523bd0cf8b0c3ab0b1ed91cb930031f61dce4ffbe4701,02174ee672429ff94304321cdae1fc1e487edf658b34bd1d36da03761658a2bb09

In this case, the public key and signature are put in the withness field, so there is no need for the sigscript, just have this field and the nodes know how to process it ?

Type 3 transactions:
(hash: 020a904cf5ca49f7ceffd5414eb382be49a80a4c31f52a7464e5157cb1859208)

357ubMvRj-MDmRHj6JL

Pkscript

OP_HASH160

259d7de4aa5acf5a495f49767377ac16c0d1bc61

OP_EQUAL

Sigscript

160014a5a20a71c933a7f71ce6856786a6a14791ac28aa

Witness
3044022044df85a6ba31572c045a1621f9540b9aca0545b2662a69ece2d5d0bd3c1a619b0220048b3f3edc075a8520773587229817b37b5c78621d68f31e0a15882b27df948b01,02b916b73543393d3516fc2679fe3fdd06a754d94d61269efad0664b28e5c9fc89

In this case both sigscript and withness are present why? And how can I interpret the sigscript to see for myself if the transaction is valid? That is, if I can do that.